# Null Pointer exception with callable in java

Tags: java, executorservice, callable

I am using executor service to spawn multiple callable threads for parallel execution. In the call method (overridden) of the class which implements callable, I check for a specific data. If the data is present I will return the data, else I will return null. When I execute the code, I'm getting `NullPointerException`. Can we return null from call method?

Basically of this syntax:

```
public string call ()
{
if (data)
return data;
else
return null;
}
```

Something of this kind.

Comment: Does the code that submits the `Callable`s to the `ExecutorService` do anything with the returned `Future` objects? And where does the NullPointerException occur?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can return null, below is the sample code which is working fine, Probably in the call method you would have been accessing an object which is not created

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);     
        Future f2 =executorService1.submit(new callable());
        System.out.println("f2 " + f2.get());       
        executorService1.shutdown();
    }

}


class callable implements Callable<String> {
    public String call() {       
        if(1==1)
           return null;
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
}
```